# Protocol violation error 08P01 when conditionally querying Postgres with IN clause

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I keep getting Postgres error 08P01 when I try to select multiple rows of data with the IN clause.

Below is a snippet of my code ...

```
stripeRouter.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const order = req.body as { product_uuid: string; quantity: number }[];
    const allProductIds = order.map((item) => item.product_uuid);
    const productsInDb = await pool.query(
      "SELECT product_uuid, price FROM product WHERE product_uuid IN ($1) AND inventory > 0",
      allProductIds
    );
    ...
```

Looking up the code id it seems this is some sort of connection error. And the error goes away if `allProductIds` contains only 1 item.

Here's the error thrown in my express router from node pg

```
"original": {
   "length": 137,
   "name": "error",
   "severity": "ERROR",
   "code": "08P01",
   "file": "postgres.c",
   "line": "1675",
   "routine": "exec_bind_message"
}
```

Comment: 1) FYI, Postgres 9.4 is two years past EOL. For this case the docs are still relevant, but I would look at newer docs for most things. 2) What is the complete error message? Add as update to your question.

Comment: You can't bind multiple scalars to one place holder.  You can generally bind an array to one placeholder, but would then need to use `product_uuid = ANY($1)` rather than `IN`.

Comment: @jjanes unfortunately using ANY did not fix the problem

Comment: You removed the reference to 9.4.  So what *is* the version you are using?

Comment: You need to look at the full error message.  Since node seems to hide it from you, you can find it in the database server's log file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on Github Q&A which shows the proper way to use the `IN` clause
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values

So the above case can be fixed in the following way:

```
const order = req.body as { product_uuid: string; quantity: number }[];
    const allProductIds = order.map((item, index) => item.product_uuid);

    const productsInDb = await pool.query(
      `SELECT product_uuid, price FROM product WHERE product_uuid IN (${allProductIds
        .map((id, i) => `$${i + 1}`)
        .join(",")})`,
      allProductIds
    );
...
```

Comment: Notice that this will fail (i.e. crash with a syntax error) when `allProductIds` is empty. Why not just use the `ANY` solution outlined in exactly the FAQ section you linked?